# what is difference between make constructor and assignment a variable after creating an instance?

Tags: python, oop

I am struggling to get a point difference between

```
class Item:
  def __init__(self, name):
    self.name = name

item = Item("Phone")
```

and assign variable like this

```
class Item:
   def __str__(self):
     return self.name

item = Item()
item.name = "Phone"
```

i have spent more than 2 hours in order to understand, but i could not find an answer for my question

Comment: The `__init__` in your example is an extremely simple one. The usefulness of `__init__` is clearer when you consider the other things you can do inside `__init__`, for example validating the values given, applying defaults and so on. Some of the examples here are useful: https://realpython.com/python-class-constructor/#providing-custom-object-initializers

Comment: The second example is considered problematic by pylint: https://pylint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/messages/warning/attribute-defined-outside-init.html Another point is that the second example disallows some optimizations (shared keys in `__dict__`)

Answer (score 0):

In the first case, all instance of the class `Item` will have the attribute `name`.  In the second case, you are adding the attribute `name` to a single instance only of the class `Item`.  (The `__str__` method is independent of assigning the `name` attribute dynamically.)

A class is like a schematic that you define for how to create objects.  The object are what you actually use (most of the time).

```
class Item:                       # every object i make is called "Item"
    def __init__(self, name):     # creating an object requires a name
        self.name = name          # the name is stored as the attribute "name"

item = Item('banana')             # create an item with name=banana
```

Many objects in Python can have additional attributes assigned to them dynamically as you demonstrated above.  This goes outside of the schematic setup by the class, but it totally allowed.

```
item = Item('banana')
item.is_tasty = True              # nom nom nom...
```

Generally you don't dynamically assign attributes because it is much hard for someone else to reason about your code if attributes start making appearances outside of the class definition.

Dynamic attribute assignment works outside of classes their instances as well.  For instance, you can assign an attribute to a function (I believe django used to do this).  Again, this is not standard practice, but it is possible.

```
def running_sum(x):
  running_sum.total += x
  return running_sum.total

running_sum.total = 0

print(running_sum(3))
print(running_sum(8))
print(running_sum(9))
# prints:
# 3
# 11
# 20
```

Answer (score 0):

Meh, In the first case you need to introduce the name in order instantiate. And In the second you don't.
Another difference is, just do `print(item)` and you see the difference.

Answer (score 0):

`__init__` is a convenience so that you don't *need* to make the assignment after creation.

When you call a type, you can imagine the definition is something like this:

```
def Item_(name):
    obj = Item.__new__(Item, name)
    if isinstance(obj, Item):
        obj.__init__(name)
    return obj

item = Item_("Phone")
```

When `__init__` gets called, `self` is bound to the new instance of `Item`, so that "inside" the call to `Item`, you have `self` bound to the object that *will* be assigned to `item` and you have `name` bound to the string `"Phone"`, so that `self.name = name` inside `__init__` is exactly equivalent to `item.name = "Phone"` outside.

---

## Digging deeper

You might consider my having to distinguish between the function name `Item_` and the actual class name `Item` a bit of a wart. Recognize, though, that the definition of `Item_` is actually a pure-Python "simulation" of `type.__call__`.

(Recall that `__new__` is a static method, just special-cased so that you don't need to explicitly decorate it as such if you override it.)

```
# Since type is the metaclass, self is an instance of the metaclass,
# namely the class being instantiated.
def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    obj = self.__new__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    if isinstance(obj, self):
        obj.__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    return obj

item = Item("Phone")
# item = Item.__call__("Phone")
#      = type.__call__(Item, "Phone")
```

With this definition in mind, we can "inline" the definitions of `type.__call__` and `Item.__init__` so that `item = Item("Phone")` becomes

```
item = Item.__new__(Item, "Phone")
if isinstance(item, Item):
    item.name = "Phone"
```

The whole business of checking the type of the value returned by `__new__` is necessary because `__new__` doesn't necessarily return an instance of the type specified by its first argument. But in this case it does (we haven't overridden `Item.__new__` to do anything so odd), so we can further simplify our inlining to

```
item = Item.__new__(Item, "Phone")
item.name = "Phone"
```

And since we *didn't* override `__new__`, `Item.__new__` resolves to `object.__new__`, which accepts but ignores all but its first argument, so we could further inline the call to `__new__` and drop the ignored argument

```
item = object.__new__(Item)
item.name = "Phone"
```

which now looks a lot like your second example.